# Including submodules in git checkout to GIT_WORK_TREE in hook

Tags: git, githooks, git-checkout

Is it possible to include submodules when using the following code in a post-update hook?

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/path/to/directory git checkout -f
```

What other options would I have to distribute code, including submodules from a post-update hook?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The question "[Using `git submodule update --init` on a post hook](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7593467/6309)" mentions the error message you could see if using this in your `post-update` hook:

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/path/to/directory git submodule update --init
```

That would give a:

```
remote: You need to run this command from the toplevel of the working tree.
```

So it is best to `cd` directly in the target repo and run your command from there:

```
export GIT_DIR=$(pwd)

cd /path/to/target/workingtree

git checkout -f master
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

However, as shown in "[How do I init/update a git submodule in a working tree after pushing to a bare working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446681/how-do-i-init-update-a-git-submodule-in-a-working-tree-after-pushing-to-a-bare-w)":

> It looks like when your running "git submodule update" you can't set the `GIT_WORK_TREE`:
>   **it will try to use this as the working tree for the submodule, not for the super project**.

The blog post "[Git push with submodules: a how-to guide](http://aaronadams.ca/post/37345904654/git-push-with-submodules)" by Aaron Adams describe similar error messages as the [OP iliveinapark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/405161/iliveinapark) shows in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16008318/including-submodules-in-git-checkout-to-git-work-tree-in-hook#comment22865072_16008587):

> Sadly, this doesn't work, I suspect because my repo is a bare repo.
>   The error that I get following these commands is:

```
fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree
```

> If, to overcome the above error, I use something like:

```
git --git-dir=<my bare repo> --work-tree=<where I export to> submodule update --init --recursive
```

> I get:

```
fatal: working tree '<where I export to>' already exists. Clone of '<submodule repo>' into submodule path '<submodule path>' failed
```

---

The blog post mentioned above suggests an approach based on a *non-bare* repo (which usually *isn't* recommended for pushing to, but is necessary in this case) :

#### Using Git to manage a website with submodules: the right way

> First, let’s create a universal post-receive hook, one that I won’t need to change on a per-repository basis:

```
[aaron@aaronadams]$ cat > /usr/local/share/git-core/templates/hooks/post-receive.sample
#!/bin/sh
#
# An example hook script to update the working tree, including its
# submodules, after receiving a push.
#
# This hook requires core.worktree to be explicitly set, and
# receive.denyCurrentBranch to be set to false.
#
# To enable this hook, rename this file to "post-receive".

# Read standard input or hook will fail
while read oldrev newrev refname
do
:
done

# Unset GIT_DIR or the universe will implode
unset GIT_DIR

# Change directory to the working tree; exit on failure
cd `git config --get core.worktree` || exit

# Force checkout
git checkout --force

# Force update submodules
git submodule update --init --recursive --force
[aaron@aaronadams]$ chmod +x /usr/local/share/git-core/templates/hooks/post-receive.sample
```

> Now let’s go ahead and break all the rules.
>
> We’re going to:
>
> - initialize a non-bare Git repository, right in our website directory;
> - make sure it can receive from git push;
> - explicitly set its working tree to its parent directory;
> - and enable our hook we just created.

```
[aaron@aaronadams]$ cd /var/www/vhosts/aaronadams.ca/sites/staging.aaronadams.ca
[aaron@aaronadams]$ git init && git config --bool receive.denyCurrentBranch false && git config --path core.worktree ../ && mv .git/hooks/post-receive.sample .git/hooks/post-receive
Initialized empty Git repository in /var/www/vhosts/aaronadams.ca/sites/staging.aaronadams.ca/.git/
```

> Finally, on our local machine, we’ll change our remote to reflect the location of our new repository, and push.

```
[aaron@aaronadams]$ git remote set-url staging aaron@aaronadams.ca:sites/staging.aaronadams.ca
[aaron@aaronadams]$ git push staging master
remote: Submodule 'codeigniter' (git://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter.git) registered for path 'codeigniter'
remote: Cloning into 'codeigniter'...
remote: Submodule path 'codeigniter': checked out 'fd24adf31255822d6aa9a5d2dce9010ad2ee4cf0'
To aaron@aaronadams.ca:sites/staging.aaronadams.ca
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

> Holy crap, it worked!
>
> Not only is this method compatible with submodules, it also requires just **one command to set up a new remote repository** (which, okay, consists of four commands).
>   It also keeps the repository and the working tree in the same place; and with no absolute paths required in our configuration or hook files, it’s now **completely portable** as well.

---

The [OP iliveinapark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/405161/iliveinapark) [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16008318/including-submodules-in-git-checkout-to-git-work-tree-in-hook/16008587?noredirect=1#comment22907880_16008587) though:

> This became a bit too fiddly, though, so I went with a simple forced checkout, and will manage updating my submodules manually.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271839/how-can-i-init-update-git-submodules-in-a-remote is also interesting

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sadly, this doesn't work, I suspect because my repo is a bare repo. The error that I get following these commands is:

`fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree`

Comment: If, to overcome the above error, I use something like:

 `git --git-dir=<my bare repo> --work-tree=<where I export to> submodule update --init --recursive`

I get:

 `fatal: working tree '<where I export to>' already exists.
Clone of '<submodule repo>' into submodule path '<submodule path>' failed`

Comment: @iliveinapark ok, I have edited the answer and reference an alternative approach.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, VonC. This became a bit too fiddly, though, so I went with a simple forced checkout, and will manage updating my submodules manually. I do appreciate your efforts, though.

Comment: @iliveinapark ok, I have added your conclusion to this answer, for more visibility.

Comment: For the record, I had to find a new approach again when I had to work with git-svn for a particular client. There was just no way to get submodules to `dcommit`. Instead, I set up my former submodules as remotes, using `fetch` and `read-tree` to update them as necessary. It's far less fiddly than submodules, which I've since abandoned completely. If you're interested, my process is documented here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14718080/802414