Git use a worktree as a submodule
I have a git repository that I would like to reuse in another project as a library.
So I have this kind of library (Lib A) that has quite a lot of branches for different configurations and I want to use this as part of another git repository (Project B).
-> Lib A (branch A)
  - config ...
-> Project B
  - src
     lib
      - Lib A (submodule branch Z)

So my question would be is it possible to reuse the same git clone of the repository as a submodule? And if so are there any traps or downsides I should be aware of.
So far the only way I saw is to add a submodule that again clones the full repository. This obviously means if I have local changes that sometimes need testing I need to push and pull again.
Thanks for your thoughts

There is no builtin way in Git. On Linux you can use symlinks or bind-mounts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21077493/how-to-use-submodules-publicly-but-symlinks-to-a-single-clone-locally In Windows it would be much harder, close to impossible to do.

The thing you must remember when you share a worktree between submodule worktrees is that every superproject remembers commit IDs for its submodules so once you change the shared worktree all superproject become dirty until you return the shared worktree to the previous commit or commit the change in all superprojects. Sharing a single worktree between multiple superprojects that point to different commits is impossible.
